# syntax error at or near "psql" when trying to access database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I'm quite new with Postgres and I have trouble connecting it to my rails project.
Installed Postgres 9.6 on my Ubuntu 16.04, created a database and a superuser with a password for it but every time I try to connect to this database nothing happens

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exEj7.png)

Comment: `psql` is not an SQL statement. If you want to reconnection to a different database within `psql`, use `\connect databasename`.

Comment: This worked! thanks. got another issue tho. I updated the gem file to 
gem 'pg' , '0.18.4'
#gem 'sqlite3'
then I ran bundle install and then I did db:create db:migrate and I got an error: 
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "kickassgirls"
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"kickassgirlsdb", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "username"=>"kickassgirls", "password"=>"tina123"}
rails aborted!

Comment: I also updated the database.yml file to:
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: kickassgirlsdb
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: kickassgirls
  password: tina123
 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: kickassgirlsdb
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: kickassgirls
  password: tina123

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `connect kickassgirlsdb` to connect to kickassgirlsdb database instead of `psql kickassgirlsdb`.